# Adding Claims to access token using JWT Grant in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, wso2, claims, wso2-identity-server

I have a single node setup of WSO2 API manager and WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager.

I have created a service provider(SP1) from which I'm generating a JWT token using client-credential grant type. I'm also adding some claims(lets say country) in the JWT token using openid scope and configuring the claims in service provider.

Now I created another service provider(SP2) from which I want to generate my access token using JWT Grant type and the JWT token generated above(from SP1) as JWT assertion value.
Command I'm using to create access token from SP2 using jwt grant:

```
curl -i -X POST -u <client-id>:<client-secret> -k -d 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=<JWT-Token>' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' https://localhost:8243/token?scope=openid
```

My question have two parts:

Q - 1.) If I want to add any new claim(lets say email) at the time of using JWT grant i.e. when generating access token from SP2, how to do this?

I have tried adding extra claim configuration in SP2, it doesn't add the claims to access token except the claims that already existed in JWT token. Even if I'm not adding any claim in SP1, still it does not add new claim into access token.

Q -  2.) Lets say I have three users in my user store with given attributes:
[Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UqCz.png)

```
Name        Country         email
A           India           a@india.com
B           UK              b@uk.com
C           US              c@us.com
```

I have a service provider created by admin which is used to generte JWT token.
Now I want to add claims to this JWT token for any of these users without using password grant type. Is it possible to add user specific claims to JWT without using password grant. If Yes then how? If No then what could be the alternative I can use?